# Prove $5z^n = e^z$ has no solutions on the annulus $1 < \lvert z \rvert < 2$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove $5z^n = e^z$ has no solutions on the annulus $1 < \lvert z \rvert < 2$ for any $n \ge 1$.

If $z = a+bi$ then $5z^n = 5\lvert z \rvert^ne^{in\theta}$ and $e^z = e^ae^{bi}$.

Direction to a useful theorem(s) or techniques for this would be nice. I am in the process of teaching myself complex analysis.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouché%27s_theorem

Comment: It has $n$ solutions in $|z| <2$ as well as $|z| <1$ by Rouche's Theorem.

Comment: Rouche is useful in general, but here it is trivial that if $|z|=r$,  $1 \le r \le 2, 5r^n \ge 5r > e^r  \ge e^{\Re z} = |e^z|$